# What time is fullreqtime in Sophos logs? E.g. fullreqtime="256266588"

Tags: format, time, sophos

In the logs from Sophos there is a Parameter called fullreqtime. In my case:

```
fullreqtime="256266588"
```

How do I convert the number to a time or Duration, what is this value?

Comment: Sophos Knowledge Base says: "fullreqtime = complete time used for the URL call" (https://community.sophos.com/kb/de-de/120347)... I'd guess it is the time in ms. You could compare it to other times in the log entry. If it is in ms, then it's a long time: 256266588ms is around 71h. So this might be the total time of a URL call that was served by an internal proxy or so, and thus you might only see the time of a long "session". Just guessing, though :]

Answer (score 0):

The `fullreqtime` is the complete time used for the URL call. The times are defined in microseconds.

<sup>Source: [Enhanced Log entries for WebFilter Log](https://community.sophos.com/kb/en-us/120347)</sup>

To convert them into hours, you can use [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/) engine by typing:

- "[256266588 microseconds to hours](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=256266588%20microseconds%20to%20hours)"

It'll give you the result of 4 minutes and 16.27 seconds.